# Where should I ask a question about the legality of an action in high school?

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation

I have a question regarding the legality of withholding information about a certain subject in high school. What site would be appropriate to ask this question on? I immediately thought [Politics SE](//politics.stackexchange.com), but I can't find appropriate tags or similar-looking questions. Since it's related to children, would it be [Parenting SE](//parenting.stackexchange.com)? Is there a site I'm missing, or would this simply not be a question appropriate for StackExchange?

Comment: Have you considered [Law.SE]?

Comment: @Glorfindel Aha, that's probably what I was missing.

Comment: If it was on an university academia.se maybe?

Comment: I suspect what subject might be an important part here

Answer (score 4):

This could be on-topic for [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/); according to their [tour](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour):

> Law Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for legal professionals, students, and others with experience or interest in law.

but note that

> The answers you get here are not a substitute for legal advice, and the other contributors here aren't acting as your lawyer.

You'll need to specify more details in your actual question, e.g. the country you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a legal question, it most probably belongs on the [law](https://law.stackexchange.com) site